# Sidekiq + Rails: Delayed Extension Default Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq in my Rails app to asynchronously perform some tasks.  I've created workers for some of my more complex operations, but there are a lot of simple cases where I call `Class.delay.some_method`.  I'd like to write tests to make sure these jobs are getting enqueued correctly.

When I create a worker to perform these jobs, I can check the queueing by making assertions about `SomeWorker.jobs` in my specs.  Is there a way to do something similar when I call #delay on a class directly?  If it makes any difference, the class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assert_equal 1, Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass.jobs.size
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is just what I needed.